# Copy and update all SQL data using SSIS without removing anything

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, archive

I've been using SSIS to try and copy data from one SQL database to another using, and both are on the same server, I want a way to copy all the data on the tables from database A to database B, but I don't want to lose any data that was already moved to database B but no longer found at database A also I want to update matching data (same primary key) on database B from database A, in short copy new data, update existing data and keep removed data.

I tried to use "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task" in the SSIS but it looks like that I need to enable the option to drop the table first to enter all data, but that means that I will lose removed data, also it will take so much unnecessary time, my other option is to use the "data flow" and define source and destination tables and put lookup between them to skip already added data, but this means that I have to create a "data flow" for every table which will take so much time, so I was wondering if this is possible at all in SSIS, and if yes then what tool can I use?

Comment: An SSIS dataflow doesn't sound like the right tool here; that's for datasets rather than entire databases. You'd probably be better off using T-SQL to write dynamic batches to perform upserts against all your tables.

Comment: If its on the same server you could write scripts to do it for each table.  If you have a LOT of tables you could write some dynamic SQL to build out the queries based off system tables for table names and columns, but that could get tricky but worth it if you have that many tables and will run often.

Comment: you can use sql server data tools from visual studio and do a "data compare" thing that will allow you to sync data. but yeah, beware of deleting existing, but i think it's possible to leave it as it is too

Comment: As a side note, if you want to go down the dynamic approach, I *hope* that **every single one** of your applicable tables has a primary key, *and* that all these tables have a `rowversion` or some kind of "last updated" date and time value.